# Alternatives to logistic regression when dataset can't meet 10 events per predictor variable

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, prediction, nonparametric, unbalanced-classes

I have a dataset with a binary outcome I'd like to model, but have many more parameters than events, probably ~100 categorical parameters to test, in a dataset with 20 events in ~600 observations. 
As this dataset doesn't meet the 10 Events per Predictor Variable requirement for performing logistic regression can anyone suggest some alternatives?

Comment: What about a bayesian logistic regression?

Comment: @DemetriPananos For this use case to define a prior I'd probably have to try Empirical Bayes, I haven't looked at this for years is it still unreliabe?

Comment: Empirical Bayes will require that you use a lot of your data just to derive a suitable prior, leaving little precious data for inference.  If your problem doesn't have legitimate priors (few rarely do), you could always pass weakly informative priors.  Bayesian methods are really about bespoke modelling, and so this approach would take time and effort.  It may be one way forward, especially if you have little data and a lot of parameters to model.